# Free division of a cube?

Tags: modeling

I'm sorry if that's an obvious question (it probably is) but I'm new to blender and I couldn't find a solution to my problem so far. What I'm trying to achieve is 
divide a cube into two unregular objects so that they fit (see the image). Normally I would use the CTRL+R tool, but it only works with straight lines. How can I do it, then?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually I would recommend use of the Boolean Modifier. But since **Blender 2.72** there is a new mesh tool to intersect geometry in Edit Mode. Starting from the default Cube and a Plane in Object Mode, subdivide the Plane to your liking and use e.g. the Displace Modifier or Sculpt to give it some bumps.
[image]
[image]
Apply the Modifier and join the Cube and the Plane with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and both selected. Go to Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select only one vertex of the Cube and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and type "intersect". Choose Intersect from the popup menu. Note, that you need Blender 2.72.

[image]

Press <kbd>P</kbd> and select "By loose parts". <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of Edit Mode and delete (<kbd>X</kbd>) the part of the Plane, that lies outside of the Cube. Three objects should be left.

[image]

Two open parts from the cube, and the region of intersection. Copy the region with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

[image]

Select a part of the Cube and one region together (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. Do the same thing with the other two objects. You can now <kbd>Tab</kbd> back into Edit Mode and "remove doubles" (optional).

[image]